# How to make spacing in the multiplication table

Tags: java

I have a question. I have two-dimensional arrays with 4x4 as a multiplication table and I have to make a space between columns such that the gap between m and m is equal to the length of the last number in the given column +1.

In the code which I send, as the comments are given the ways that I tried to solve it but I did not succeed

https://gist.github.com/Isbena-4/7e3a628c55d6d9d26f428b9e268e132e

It's must look that

```
 
1 2  3  4
2 4  6  8
3 6  9 12
4 8 12 16
```

Comment: please add your code to the post.

Comment: @michalk it is already added

Comment: @SyedMehtabHassan The code needs to be in the question itself. See [mcve] for more information.

Comment: unable to understand it perfectly kindly explain it briefly with input and outputs if possible

Comment: im not entirely sure what you wnat to do but would you jsut add another space if the number is <10 ?

Comment: You just need to format each field with a number of characters.  Check out https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)  Choosing the width is the interesting part; ideally you'll keep track of your largest field as you get them.

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate over the array and find the element with the most digits in each column. Than use `%<LEN>d` format string to display it with the right length:

```java
int[][] input = {
    {1, 2, 3, 4}, 
    {2, 4, -6666, 8}, 
    {3, 6, 9, 12}, 
    {4, 8, 12, 16}
};
int n = input.length;

int[] colLengths = new int[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    int l = String.valueOf(input[j][i]).length();
    if (l > colLengths[i]) {
      colLengths[i] = l;
    }
  }
}

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    System.out.printf("%" + colLengths[j] + "d ", input[i][j]);
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

will print a well formatted grid while also handling the negative numbers:

```
1 2     3  4 
2 4 -6666  8 
3 6     9 12 
4 8    12 16
```